# No buttons on extensions.gnome.org

Tags: gnome, extension

There are no buttons in extensions.gnome.org website. So I am unable to download shell extensions. I have already installed gnome-shell in ubuntu 12.04. My GNOME screen looks very pale.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. I believe you are using Chrome to browse that website. Try use Firefox and give me feedback.

Answer (score 0):

***First you need to click on the name of the extensions [in this page](https://extensions.gnome.org/) and an ADD button will be displayed on the left side of the extension name***.

This can happen sometimes (I experienced it). Try doing these

- Refresh the page (sometimes requires several times)
- Wait for it to be viewed
- Resize the browser window
- Check you are using gnome-shell (not gnome-classic or Unity session or others)
- Try different browser.

*Waiting* and *refreshing* worked for me.

Comment: i refreshed the page . . resized the window . . checked that i am using gnome-shell . . but still the problem is not solved. . the extensions are translusent . . and there is no on off switch on the left of the extension

Comment: @HetShah can you give a screenshot? What is version of gnome-shell you are using? Please open a terminal and put the output of `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` here

Comment: @HetShah check the update