# Cannot install gnome shell extensions

Tags: 12.04, gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04, install gnome 3 and remove unity.
My gnome version is 3.4.1. The GNOME Shell extensions is installed and enabled.
When I use firefox to visit each extension page in https://extensions.gnome.org/, for example, https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5/alternative-status-menu/, there is no where to install the extensions. I am told that one can install extensions by visite these extension pages.

This is [the guide](http://www.filiwiese.com/installing-gnome-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/) I followed.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are not seeing extensions available is that they are for Gnome Shell 3.6 most likely. This was an issue I had when I was running Gnome Shell 3.2 and they moved to the 3.4 version.

The best suggestion is to update Gnome Shell with the Gnome 3 PPA

In terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After the upgrade try going to the extension site. You should be all set.

Edit: This will get you to the latest version of Gnome Shell which right now should be 3.6 if I am correct.

Answer (score 0):

Some one else made this thread before.

Try This.

**Goto Terminal**

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

[Try this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192835/no-buttons-on-extensions-gnome-org)

**Remove Gnome-shell and reinstall**

sign out and go back to gnome 2D

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

Comment: But I have installed gnome-shell. Why I need to install it again? It just says gnome-shell is already the newest version.

Comment: Actually , I think it is very simple to do that , You just need to click that On OFF Button to install the extension , If that is not the problem , then give me more detail about your problem

Comment: Oh, the problem is that there is no ON/OFF buttons in the extensions page. I don't know why, it is just different from the tutorial I followed.

Comment: And also try to remove some unnecessary extensions from the firefox 
Use firefox in Safe Mode , recommended

Comment: I just found that page, but there is no definite answer. The "methods" mentioned there don't work